# PHP Mail stops working without me editing the code

Tags: php, forms, email, input, send

I have a problem with my PHP Mail. It stops working from time to time without me even touching the code. I have a script which checks if required forms are empty. This script works. But if I fill in all the required fields I should get a text which says "Your mail was successfully sent" but I don't. But if I edit my code by just moving a bit of text some lines down and back to the original position again it works, for a while. It's often under the night it stops working. Can it be the server that is causing trouble or is it my code that I posted below?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$namn = strip_tags($_POST['namn']);
$foretag = strip_tags($_POST['foretag']);
$adress = strip_tags($_POST['adress']);
$postnr = strip_tags($_POST['postnr']);
$ort = strip_tags($_POST['ort']);
$telefon = strip_tags($_POST['telefon']);
$epost = strip_tags($_POST['epost']);
$meddelande = strip_tags($_POST['meddelande']);

function check_required_fields($required_array){
    $field_errors = array();
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname){
        if ((!isset($_POST[$fieldname])) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]))){ 
            if($_POST[$fieldname] != '0'){
                $field_errors[] = $fieldname; 
            }
        }
    }
    return $field_errors;
}

$errors = array();
$required_fields = array('namn', 'telefon', 'meddelande');
$errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields));

if(empty($errors)){

$meddelande=nl2br($meddelande);

if(empty($foretag)){ $foretag='-'; }
if(empty($adress)){ $adress='-'; }
if(empty($postnr)){ $postnr='-'; }
if(empty($ort)){ $ort='-'; }
if(empty($epost)){ $epost='-'; }

$body = 
"
Namn: <b>". $namn ."</b><br />
Företag: <b>". $foretag ."</b><br />
Adress: <b>". $adress ."</b><br />
Postnr: <b>". $postnr ."</b><br />
Ort: <b>". $ort ."</b><br />
Telefon: <b>". $telefon ."</b><br />
E-post: <b>". $epost ."</b><br /><br />
Meddelande: <b><br />". $meddelande
;

$headers = "From: $namn <webmaster@allflytt.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();

$success = mail('info@allflytt.com', 'Meddelande', $body, $headers);

}

}

?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    
            <?php
                if(!empty($errors)){
                    echo "<p class=\"field_error\">De rödmarkerade fälten måste fyllas i.</p>";
                }
            ?>
            
            <?php
                if(empty($errors) && $success){
                    echo "<p class=\"p_success\">Tack för ditt meddelande! Vi kommer att besvara det inom kort.</p>";
                }
            ?>
    
    <p>
        <label for="namn">
        <?php if(!empty($errors)){if(in_array("namn", $errors)){echo "<span class=\"field_error\">";}}?>Namn: *<?php if(!empty($errors)){if(in_array("namn", $errors)){echo "</span>";}} ?>
        </label><br />
        <input type="text" name="namn" id="namn" class="text" tabindex="15" value="<?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $namn; } ?>" />
            <br />
        <label for="foretag">Företag:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="foretag" id="foretag" class="text" tabindex="20" value="<?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $foretag; }?>" />
            <br />
        <label for="adress">Adress:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="adress" id="adress" class="text" tabindex="30" value="<?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $adress; } ?>" />
            <br />
        <label for="postnr">Postnummer:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="postnr" id="postnr" class="text_medium" tabindex="40" value="<?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $postnr; } ?>" />
            <br />
        <label for="ort">Ort:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="ort" id="ort" class="text" tabindex="50" value="<?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $ort; } ?>" />
            <br />
        <label for="telefon">
        <?php if(!empty($errors)){if(in_array("telefon", $errors)){echo "<span class=\"field_error\">";}}?>Telefon: *<?php if(!empty($errors)){if(in_array("telefon", $errors)){echo "</span>";}} ?>
        </label><br />              
        <input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" class="text" tabindex="60" value="<?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $telefon; } ?>" />
            <br />
        <label for="epost">E-post:</label><br />                
        <input type="text" name="epost" id="epost" class="text" tabindex="70" value="<?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $epost; } ?>" />
            <br />
        <label for="meddelande">
        <?php if(!empty($errors)){if(in_array("meddelande", $errors)){echo "<span class=\"field_error\">";}}?>Meddelande: *<?php if(!empty($errors)){if(in_array("meddelande", $errors)){echo "</span>";}} ?>
        </label><br />              
        <textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" class="textarea" tabindex="80"><?php if(!empty($errors)){ echo $meddelande; } ?></textarea>
            <br />  
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka" class="submit" />
    </p>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Changed to a new server host. No issues any more!

Answer (score 1):

could not find if anything wrong in your code.
check if APC cache is enabled in your server.
sometimes it creates problem in taking updated code.

if you are using SMTP server then mail() function may not work.
you can use PEARS for this.

Comment: Talked to my web hosting company and the APC cache is already enabled. He is looking further into the issue. But it has to be something with the server right? If not, I'm clueless.

Comment: ok, are you using SMTP server?
if yes then mail may not work.
use pears to send mail.
you can refer this.
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: I think so. I asked my server host and he said that SMTP was configured on the mail server. I have now tried to use pear to send mail but no success. I just get a blank window when hitting submit. But can this really be the problem? Why would it occasionally send my mails?

Comment: My server host sais that I don't need to use pears to send mail with his server. After a couple of days looking into this I haven't found a solution. One thing I've noticed for sure is that it's under the night it stops working. Then it starts working by me just uploading a random html/php file that is already on the server. I don't even have to make changes to the file, just uploading the exact same file makes it work again. Have looked through my code several of times and cant find anything wrong with my code either. I really appreciate the help so far. Hopefully you can help me further :)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem. Turned out the browser, by error, sometimes double-posts your form; One time with content and another time without content.

If no content is submitted to your script, obviously there's nothing to act upon. There are a number of ways to check on this, but they way I discovered it was a desperate last resort measure where I sent emails to myself with each run of the script. And I showed that I often got two mails where the script had run only once.

It's worht trying :)

Comment: The thing is that the mails aren't sent at all. As I mentioned the error check works but if I fill in all required fields it doesn't show the success message and the mail is not even sent.