# PHP Mail stops working

Tags: php, forms, email, input, send

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Mail stops working without me editing the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258761/php-mail-stops-working-without-me-editing-the-code)

I've had a problem with a clients mail function for a while. The thing is that the mail I use to receive the mails stops receiving mails from time to time. I've noticed this because when I change from my clients mail (info@allflytt.com) to my own (daniel@codia.se) it starts working properly. Also the "success function" gives me the message "The mail was not sent." when I use my clients mail (info@allflytt.com). So the problem seems to be located in the mailadress wich somehow, sometimes, doesn't accept the mails. This happens a couple of times every day and all I can do is wait for it to work again. I've posted the code below.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$mottagare = 'info@allflytt.com';
$titel = 'Meddelande';

$namn = strip_tags($_POST['namn']);
$foretag = strip_tags($_POST['foretag']);
$adress = strip_tags($_POST['adress']);
$postnr = strip_tags($_POST['postnr']);
$ort = strip_tags($_POST['ort']);
$telefon = strip_tags($_POST['telefon']);
$epost = strip_tags($_POST['epost']);
$meddelande = strip_tags($_POST['meddelande']);

$meddelande=nl2br($meddelande);

$body = 
"
Namn: <b>". $namn ."</b><br />
Företag: <b>". $foretag ."</b><br />
Adress: <b>". $adress ."</b><br />
Postnr: <b>". $postnr ."</b><br />
Ort: <b>". $ort ."</b><br />
Telefon: <b>". $telefon ."</b><br />
E-post: <b>". $epost ."</b><br /><br />
Meddelande: <b><br />". $meddelande
;

$headers =  'From: '. $namn .' <webmaster@allflytt.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$success = mail($mottagare, $titel, $body, $headers);

}

?>

            <?php
                if(!($success)){
                    echo "<p class=\"field_error\">The mail was not sent.</p>";
                }
            ?>

            <?php
                if($success){
                    echo "<p class=\"p_success\">Great! The mail was sent.</p>";
                }
            ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

    <p>
        <label for="namn">Namn: *</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="namn" id="namn" class="text" tabindex="15" />
            <br />
        <label for="foretag">Företag:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="foretag" id="foretag" class="text" tabindex="20" />
            <br />
        <label for="adress">Adress:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="adress" id="adress" class="text" tabindex="30" />
            <br />
        <label for="postnr">Postnummer:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="postnr" id="postnr" class="text_medium" tabindex="40" />
            <br />
        <label for="ort">Ort:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="ort" id="ort" class="text" tabindex="50" />
            <br />
        <label for="telefon">Telefon: *</label><br />               
        <input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" class="text" tabindex="60" />
            <br />
        <label for="epost">E-post:</label><br />                
        <input type="text" name="epost" id="epost" class="text" tabindex="70" />
            <br />
        <label for="meddelande">Meddelande: *</label><br />             
        <textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" class="textarea" tabindex="80"></textarea>
            <br />  
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka" class="submit" />
    </p>

    </form>
```

Comment: Check the values of $namn (limit to letters, hyphens and spaces). Check also with your host as they may filter some emails.

Comment: It seems your code is working fine, but you mail-server / the receiving mail server is not. You might get better help at for example http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I'll take a look at the other forum. And I've hade some conversations with my web host already and he is looking into it as we speak. What I know so far is that APC cache is enabled on the server and it's using SMTP to send mails. I got the suggestion that maybe then I needed to use PEARS to send mail by his SMTP server but according to him I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Changed to a new server host. No issues any more!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely with the $namn variable, which can get practically any value, and therefore could either not be a valid e-mail at all, or could be an e-mail that's being blocked by the recipient.

Firstly you should make sure that $namn is a valid e-mail, but personally I would recommend that you use a single constant address for your From, preferably one the domain of which resolves to your mail server's IP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
I did a test were I changed '. $namn .' to just Message
($headers =  'From: Message <webmaster@allflytt.com>' . "\r\n";)
but the problem is still there. The code I posted is also a stripped down version. The real version has a function wich checks required fields and $namn in one of them, so it can't be empty. "Namn" is also simply translated to "name" in english so the form should not contain an e-mail adress.

Comment: I see. I checked the MX record for your domain and it seems that it's not pointing to the same domain as your site, but a similar IP--but this is not enough information to determine whether they are connected.

Basically if your web server and your mail server isn't the same one, and you are trying to send email locally, it might not work. However, if your web server already sends through that mail server then it will work.